# solr core vs elasticsearch which feature?

Tags: elasticsearch, solr

We are planning to migrate three applications from solr to elasticsearch. One issue that we are facing is, all these applications use single instance of solr and they protect their data from other applications using **cores** in solr. so, each app has its own core in solr. Due to this no other app can read/update its data.

I have gone through some of the comparison sites and introductory tutorials on elasticsearch but couldn't figure out feature that can be used from elasticsearch to achieve the same. Getting separate elasticsearch instance for each app is not an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The same concept as a core in Solr is [an index in Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/documents-indices.html). Each index lives separately from the others (with its own index configuration / schema / etc.) in the same way as a core or a collection in Solr.

> An index can be thought of as an optimized collection of documents and each document is a collection of fields, which are the key-value pairs that contain your data. By default, Elasticsearch indexes all data in every field and each indexed field has a dedicated, optimized data structure.